# Is there an easy way in Ruby on Rails of adding a total time duration within a specific date range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have a meetings table:

```bash
rails g scaffold Meetings name:string start_time:datetime end_time:datetime
```

I have calculated the duration time in between a meeting start time and end time:

meetings.rb

```
def duration
  (end_time - start_time).to_i
end
```

mettings_helper.rb

```
def duration_display(meeting)
  duration = ActiveSupport::Duration.build(meeting.duration).parts
  format('%02d hours and %02d minutes', (duration[:hours]||0), (duration[:minutes]||0), (duration[:seconds]||0))
end
```

meetings/index.html

```
 <td><%= duration_display meeting %></td>
```

But I'm struggling on how to calculate the total time duration of meetings within a day and total time of meetings within a week period.

Is there an easy way in Ruby on Rails of summing the total time durations within a specific date range? Below is a sample of the output i am trying to get:

```plaintext
Start Time              End time                Duration                
2021-08-01 01:08:00     2021-08-01 03:20:00     02 hours and 12 minutes     
2021-08-01 14:20:00     2021-08-01 17:04:00     02 hours and 44 minutes
```

Total meeting time for 2021-08-01 is 4 hours 56 minutes

Total meeting time this week is 15 hours 28 minutes (based from Sunday to Sunday)

Comment: *"Total meeting time this week is 15 hours 28 minutes"* -- Why? How can we deduce that from your data? What exactly do you mean by a "week period"?

Comment: Also, the above numbers seem wrong? The first meeting is 2 hours and **12 minutes**, and the second meeting is 2 hours and **44 minutes**, meaning the total should actually be 4 hours and **56 minutes**? Unless you have some additional logic about "rounding down" that's not mentioned in your question?

Comment: Would it be reasonable to assume that a meeting will never span across midnight, so you don't need to worry about overlap between days?

Comment: Hi Tom you are correct. I put in the wrong time when typing by accident. The above should be 4 hours 56 minutes. The total weekly 15 hours and 28 minutes is just an example number of the total time based  on weeks. So for example I am looking for the total meeting duration time per week say from Sunday to Sunday each week, so i will be able to tell how long i have spent per week in meetings. Sarah x

Comment: You could store the duration in a separate column which makes summing durations trivial.

Comment: ^^ This. Since meetings don't overlap between days, it would be easiest to just group meetings by which week their `start_date` falls in, and sum the duration column.

Comment: Also, "Sunday to Sunday" is not a good definition.. Do weeks overlap, or are one of those days supposed to be exclusive? Perhaps you mean **Monday to Sunday**, or **Sunday to Saturday**?

Comment: Hi Tom yes Monday to Sunday is what i need. I am a novice at rails so are you talking about redoing the Scaffold and add a column called Duration:datetime ?

Answer (score 0):

First Duration Time

```
star_time = Time.new(2021, 8, 1, 1,8,0), end_time = Time.new(2021, 8, 1, 3, 20, 0 )
first_duration = end_time - start_time
```

Second Duration Time

```
star_time1 = Time.new(2021, 8, 1,14,20,00), end_time2 = 
Time.new(2021,8,1, 17,04,00)
second_duration = end_time2 - star_time1
```

first_duration and second_duration time get in seconds

Now added `first_duration` and `second_duration` and get `total_seconds`

```
total_seconds = first_duration + second_duration
total_time = Time.at(total_seconds).utc.strftime(" %H  Hours %M  Minutes")
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer but i was hoping to not have to put a date in manually i was looking for an answer where it would recognis all the duration within a day and add them so for my sample it would recognise the date 2021-08-01 and calculate and show the total for that day " 4 hours 56 minutes "

Comment: your date params or variable first convert in to_time and then called this process.

Comment: Thi is other method you used. 
first_time = "02:05:16"
second_time = "02:20:13"


`def time_added(first_time, second_time)
      second_time = second_time.to_time
      first_time = first_time.to_time
      m = second_time.strftime("%M").to_i
      h = second_time.strftime("%H").to_i
      s = second_time.strftime("%S").to_i
      return (first_time + h.hours + m.minutes + s.second).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    end`

Comment: so in my helper mettings.rb             def time_added(first_time, second_time) 
second_time = second_time.to_time 
first_time = first_time.to_time 
m = second_time.strftime("%M").to_i 
h = second_time.strftime("%H").to_i s = second_time.strftime("%S").to_i 
return (first_time + h.hours + m.minutes + s.second).strftime("%H:%M:%S") 
end then in                                                                                          meetings/index.html

 <td><%= time_added meeting %></td>         i get wrong number of arguments error